# HP ProBook 4710s - Fan running constantly at full

Tags: hp, fan

- HP ProBook 4710s
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Linux 3.13.0-77-generic

After the some update of Ubuntu, I lost control over the fan. (May be after update of the kernel?)

`lm-sensor` didn't help me.

Now the fan is always running on maximum.

Comment: is your fan working fine in other O/S(like Windows)? Is it the problem only in Linux?

Comment: Yes, it is the problem only in Linux.

Comment: I have HP Laptop also. HP laptops have the best of the configuration at the same price compared to Dell, Toshiba, Lenovo etc...but they are not well built. I have the high fan issue with my HP laptop which finally HP replaced with a brand new laptop...new laptop is not that bad(at least 60% noise has been reduced in new laptop). Fan noise is in Windows as well as Linux. There is something called HP Cool Sense(http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02638953) which can help in Windows but nothing for Linux. So in Linux you are own your own unless it's HP which installed Linux on your laptop.

Comment: which graphics card is the PC equipped with?

Comment: $ sudo lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550] [1002:9552] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])...

Comment: Install latest Ubuntu and proprietary drivers for video. Maybe will be reasonable to check bios options for such fan work.